# cv::flann::index::knnsearch values of indices and dists

Tags: c++, opencv3.0

ok given the following code

```
index.knnSearch(mat,indices,dists,3);
for (int i = 0; i < indices.rows; i++ )
{
   indices.at<int>(i,0) // this is the index of the match
   indices.at<int>(i,1) // ????? what is this?
   indices.at<int>(i,2) // and this?
}
```

also for dists, what do I do with the 3 values in each row? how do I make it into a useful ratio or percentage match?
in the indices I need to know how many descriptors out of 500 matched, I'm sure that data shows that somehow, but I don't understand it. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is the call:-

```
knnSearch(mat,indices,dists,N);
```

Note - N is a value passed by the caller.

On return,

> "*indices*" refer to the array having the "N" closest neighbours found
>   by the algorithm.
>
> "*dists*" refers to the distance of the same indices.

So, in the case mentioned in the question, **N=3**, and the 3 closest neighbours are returned along with their distances. How you use it it really upto the use-case.

Comment: so the second part of my question, how can I convert the results in dists to a percentage when using binary descriptors?

Comment: ok I did some reading about binary descriptors and if I understand it then the number it returns is the amount of differing bits between the 2 matches. so for 500 descriptors at 32 BYTES each so 256 bits, 256 X 500 descriptors 128,000 bits per set of descriptors so a 90% match would mean a value of 12,800 so anything lower than that is a good match. Did I do that right?

Comment: I think you should be doing knnMatch instead. Something like http://find-object.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-0.4.3/find_object/example/main.cpp

Comment: it's not shown here, but I am matching a frame of a video to every other frame of every other video in the database, I'm sure the nested for loops would be far too slow for this. Wouldn't they?

Comment: Slow is relative but if this is the use-case, HW acceleration is definitely recommended. You can accept the answer if the original query is answered.

Comment: the second part of my question wasn't answered, read my comments please

Comment: What distance metric has been specified in building the index ? If it supports binary descriptors, then you just need to bin them based on the distance number.